# Error creating hybrid app mobile salesforce sdk

Tags: mobile, hybrid, cordova, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I have been struggling for a couple of days creating an hybrid app with salesforce mobile sdk.
I managed to execute some samples app in by cloning the saleseforce mobile sdk git repo and following these instructions: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/blob/master/hybrid/README.md.

I wanted to create a new app from scratch cause I need to import some plugins, I couldn't do it with the sample projects (cordova says they are not valid cordova project directories).

I followed several guides: http://paste.scsys.co.uk/465779

and other variants.... (I didn't save all the links)

I always receive that error when I build the project:

```
    Running command: C:\Users\giovi\Desktop\testApp\TestApp\platforms\android\cordov
a\build.bat
Buildfile: C:\Users\giovi\Desktop\testApp\TestApp\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\giovi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity...

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\giovi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:577: ../../
external/cordova/framework resolve to a path with no project.properties file for
 project C:\Users\giovi\Desktop\testApp\TestApp\plugins\com.salesforce\src\andro
id\libs\SalesforceSDK

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\Users\giovi\Desktop\testApp\TestApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\
q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\giovi\Deskt
op\testApp\TestApp\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolut
e.dir=ant-gen
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\Users\giovi\Desktop\testApp\TestA
pp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

I don't think it's a problem related with my environment because if a I try to create a cordova project without the salesforce Mobile Sdk plugins, the compilation step works as expected.

I've tried several options and I don't know what to do know, could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would happen in a few cases

A) You do not have a clean build. Run the following commands in your app folder (assuming you have added android platform with cordova)

```
cd platforms/android
ant clean
cd ../../
cordova build android
```

B) Make sure the `sdk.dir` variable in your `project.properties` is pointing to the correct location

C) The value of `android.library.reference.1` parameter is not set correctly

D) check that your config.xml has these tags

```
<platform name="ios">
</platform>
<platform name="android">
</platform>
```

This seems a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968929/cordova-phonegap-android-java-ant-issue-on-build) with recent Cordova version

Comment: Hi Gaurav and thanks for the reply!
I ran the "ant clean" command you told me but I got a "build failure with that error
`BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\giovi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:459: ../../
external/cordova/framework resolve to a path with no project.properties file for
 project C:\Users\giovi\Desktop\myApp\myapp\plugins\com.salesforce\src\android\l
ibs\SalesforceSDK`

Comment: my project.properties is set like this:
`target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
manifestmerger.enabled=true
android.library.reference.2=..\\..\\plugins\\com.salesforce\\src\\android\\libs\\SmartSync`
You can see that android.library.reference.1 points to CordovaLIb, a folder that does exist in my project.
sdk.dir seems to point to the correct folder.
There must be something I'm missing but I don't understand what...

Comment: can you confirm your sdk and cordova versions?

Comment: Updated my answer, verify point d)

Comment: Thanks for your helping! Unfortunately the last trick didn't solve the problem. I guess the problem is related to the salesforce mobile sdk plugin cause I'm able to build cordova project without it. 

My cordova version is 4.2.0

This is my current sdk situation:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C_87COhuKiRkFNeWh2eGtqLUk/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C_87COhuKiNGFXMk1DS0poY3M/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C_87COhuKiN05VNnlGeGhKdHc/view?usp=sharing

I hope this information could better clarify my problem

Thanks

Comment: Mobile SDK 3.1 uses Cordova 3.6.4. I think for some reason this is happening because your project is not pointing to the right Cordova version

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake in specifying my cordova version. I suppose 4.2.0 is the cordova cli version (retrieved by using the "cordova -v" command). I created a new empty project and added the android platform. Inside the "platforms/android/cordova/version" file I can read that  I'm using the 3.6.4 version:

// Coho updates this line:
var VERSION = "3.6.4";

I'm short of ideas now...

Comment: ../../ external/cordova/framework so this points to 3.6.4 or to 4.2.0?

Comment: I have no directory inside my project with that path... there is a path starting with that directory inside the mobile sdk git version though. I've tried to create a project directly inside the sdk git version folder, obtaining the same error. do you think I have to set up a link or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's a known issue with 'cordova build'. You should be able to build your project using eclipse though.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Please check the workaround I used to build the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I managed to compile my project. I installed a fresh Linux environment (ubuntu 14.10) using a virtual machine. In this new system I configured all the dependencies: java, jdk, git, ant, adt...
I can now build a cordova project using the salesforce mobile sdk by following these steps (different from the ones provided in the user guide):

1)cordova create test com.company.test test

2)cd test

3)cordova platform add android

4)cordova build (without this first build it won't compile after)

5)cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin

6)add bootconfig.json file properly configured

7)cordova build

8)cordova run